# Check the defined variable is empty or not in Ansible

Tags: ansible

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
           files_list:
           #it may contain the file_list like 
           #file_list: 
           #     - "file*"
  tasks: 
       - name: copy
         copy:
             src: "{{item}}"
             dest: "/tmp/"
         with_fileglob: "{{files_list}}"
         when: files != None
```

I want to copy some multiple files with a specific pattern from the files_list. **but sometimes the file_list may be empty**. so **how to check if the file_list is empty** I have tried above code but it doesn't work. it is giving me following error

```
The full traceback is:<br>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 104, in run<br>
    items = self._get_loop_items()<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 245, in _get_loop_items<br>
    items = wrap_var(mylookup.run(terms=loop_terms, variables=self._job_vars, wantlist=True))<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py", line 60, in run<br>
    term_file = os.path.basename(term)<br>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 121, in basename<br>
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1<br>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'<br>
fatal: [machine1]: FAILED! => {<br>
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", <br>
    "stdout": ""<br>
}
```

Can you also explain whats this mean.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q: ***"Check whether the defined variable is empty or not in Ansible."***

A: Simply test the variable. An empty list evaluates to `False`. This also covers the case when the variable is not defined. YAML `None` is Python `null`. `None` also evaluates to `False`. For example

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: The variable files is an empty list or None.
  when: not files|default(None)
```

- In the loop, it's not necessary to test whether the list is empty or not. An empty list will be skipped anyway.
- YAML string is a list of characters. An empty string evaluates to `False` the same way as an empty list does.

---

**Notes**

1. The evaluation of '*not item*' works in the context of this question if the variable is a string, list, dictionary, or None. if the variable is a boolean or number this test does not work. See the self-explaining test below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ not item }}"
      loop:
        - ''
        - []
        - {}
        -
        - null
        - true
        - false
        - 1
        - 0
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=[]) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item={}) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=True) => 
  msg: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=False) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => 
  msg: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => 
  msg: true
```

2. To fix this problem [test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) the variable is [*iterable*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.iterable)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item is iterable }}"
      loop:
        - ''
        - []
        - {}
        -
        - null
        - false
        - 0
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=[]) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item={}) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=False) => 
  msg: false
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => 
  msg: false
```

Complete test: The variable is empty or None

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: The variable is empty or None.
      when:
        - not item
        - item is iterable or item is none
      loop:
        - ''
        - []
        - {}
        -
        - null
        - true
        - false
        - 1
        - 0
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=) => 
  msg: The variable is empty or None.
ok: [localhost] => (item=[]) => 
  msg: The variable is empty or None.
ok: [localhost] => (item={}) => 
  msg: The variable is empty or None.
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg: The variable is empty or None.
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg: The variable is empty or None.
skipping: [localhost] => (item=True) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=False) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=1) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=0)
```

3. A dictionary is also iterable. A list of the keys is used

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ files|list }}"
      vars:
        files:
          a: 1
          b: 2
          c: 3
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: a
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: b
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if it is empty you need to give as below

```
when: not files_list
```

See Default rules here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/rules/default_rules.html

It states: Don’t compare to empty string, use `when: var` rather than `when: var != ""` (or conversely `when: not var` rather than `when: var == ""`)